# Fast filter in a list of records with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a list with about 10 000 customers on a web page and need to be able to search within this list for matching input. It works with some delay and I'm looking for the ways how to improve performance. Here is simplified example of HTML and JavaScript I use:

```
<input id="filter" type="text" />
<input id="search" type="button" value="Search" />
<div id="customers">
    <div class='customer-wrapper'>
        <div class='customer-info'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").on("click", function() {
            var filter = $("#filter").val().trim().toLowerCase();
            FilterCustomers(filter);
        });
    });

    function FilterCustomers(filter) {
        if (filter == "") {
            $(".customer-wrapper").show();
            return;
        }
        $(".customer-info").each(function() {
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
                $(this).parent().show();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on Search button, there is a quite long delay until I get list with matched results. Are there some better ways to filter list?

Comment: I suggest that you move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: puttin `GetRandomName`  outside of `LoadCustomers()` and make only one call by loop (changing the return to fit your needs) will improve a bit... ut codereview is your place!

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I didn't know about Code Review before. I removed test example of LoadCustomers() from my question, becuase the problem is not there at all. It is slow updating of list, that is FilterCustomers(filter) function.

Comment: The bottleneck are those `.show()` and `.hide()` stuff. Remove them from the loop: collect the items in the iteration and put them in two buckets/list, once finished `show` those in the `shown` bucket and `hide` the rest.

Comment: Why would you need 10,000 names in the DOM at one time in the first place? That's information overload for user and slow to render. Filter data instead, then update DOM

Comment: @charlietfl: you're right and I woundn't need it, but such are requirements. Clients want to have overlook of all customers in one list (without even pagination) and filter is just additional feature for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** DOM manipulation is usually slow, especially when you're appending new elements. Put all your html into a variable and append it, that results in one DOM operation and is much faster than do it for each element

```
function LoadCustomers() {
    var count = 10000;
    var customerHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var name = GetRandomName() + " " + GetRandomName();
        customerHtml += "<div class='customer-info'>" + name + "</div>";
    }
    $("#customers").append(customerHtml);
}
```

**2)** jQuery.each() is slow, use `for` loop instead

```
function FilterCustomers(filter) {
    var customers = $('.customer-info').get();
    var length = customers.length;
    var customer = null;
    var i = 0;
    var applyFilter = false;
    if (filter.length > 0) {
        applyFilter = true;
    }
    for (i; i < length; i++) {
        customer = customers[i];
        if (applyFilter && customer.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) < 0) {
            $(customer).addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(customer).removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/29ubpjgk/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your answers and comments, I've come at least to solution with satisfied results of performance. I've cleaned up redundant wrappers and made grouped showing/hiding of elements in a list instead of doing separately for each element. Here is how filtering looks now:

```
function FilterCustomers(filter) {
    if (filter == "") {
        $(".customer-info").show();
    } else {
        $(".customer-info").hide();
        $(".customer-info").removeClass("visible");
        $(".customer-info").each(function() {
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) {
                $(this).addClass("visible");
            }
        });
        $(".customer-info.visible").show();
    }
}
```

And an test example http://jsfiddle.net/vtds899r/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are iterating the records, and having 10000 it can be very slow, so my suggestion is to change slightly the structure, so you won't have to iterate:

1. Define all the css features of the list on `customer-wrapper`
   **class** and make it the *parent div of all the list elements*.
2. When your ajax request add an element, create a variable containing the name replacing spaces for underscores, let's call it  `underscore_name`.
3. Add the name to the list as:

`var customerHtml = "<div id='"+underscore_name+'>" + name + "</div>";`

Each element of the list will have an unique id that will be "almost" the same as the name, and all the elements of the list will be on the *same level* under `customer-wrapper` class.

4. For the search you can take the user input replace spaces for underscores and put in in a variable, for example `searchable_id`, and using Jquery:

`$('#'+searchable_id).siblings().hide()`;

`siblings` will hide the other elements on the same level as *searchable_id*.

The only problem that it could have is if there is a case of two or more repeated names, because it will try to create two or more divs with the same id.

You can check a simple implementation on http://jsfiddle.net/mqpsppxm/
​

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! First is really good to get rid of redundant HTML around objects to be filtered. Others won't fit, because filter should work for many matches. Besides giving names of customers to objects is bad idea as they contain many Unicode symbols (they are not all English), however customers have numeric IDs and they can be used if it would help.